# Issue using Show Data Table Option for Graphics in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

problem that I have is when I click on show data table option to look at the information about any graphic (column graphic).

I tried to solve this using CSS properties and HTML labels, JS clickon event, changing tha language and the version of Highcharts however I can't solve it.

I hope you can help me please.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @jafet Jimenez, Please add more information about your problem. It would be best if you could adapt this simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vyuh8k0L/ to show the issue.